# rar all files in a directory windows

Tags: windows, winrar

I have a folder containing multiple files inside that.

```
~/Folder/file-1
~/Folder/file-2
...
~/Folder/file-n
```

I want to make separate .rars for each of the files in ~/Folder. How can I do that using winrar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
for /r %i in (*) do rar a "%~ni%~xi.rar" "%~ni%~xi"
```

Will work. If you put this in a batch file double up on the `%` signs. Like so:

```
for /r %%i in (*) do rar a "%%~ni%%~xi.rar" "%%~ni%%~xi"
```

You could replace the `*` with an actual directory path or a batch parameter variable if you don't want this to work on the current directory.

I've used some special variable modifiers here. A partial list of those available are:

> filedrive=%~di
>
> filepath=%~pi
>
> filename=%~ni
>
> fileextension=%~xi

Comment: This is creating only one rar files with all files inside that. I want individual rar files

Comment: @Jaguar I've updated with a working version. This will add all files with same name but different extension to the same archive though. You could fix that by also using the extensions as part of the archive name though.

Comment: Ok, I've included that too now so that this will always work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [for /r](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) command.

**Example**

```
FOR /R "C:\yourdirectory\" %%G in (.) DO (
    pushd %%g
    rar a %%G
    popd
)
```

There is also some example batch files at [Using the WinRAR Command-line tools in Windows](http://comptb.cects.com/using-the-winrar-command-line-tools-in-windows/) which you might want to take a look at.

> **Using WinRAR in Batch Files**:
>
> Two batch file examples are provided, The first
> [compress_rar_rev1.bat](http://comptb.cects.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/compress_rar_rev1.bat_.txt) provides several compression options such as
> such as compressing all files in a folder or a folder and its
> subfolders, with options to compress them into a single archive or
> individually and to include or exclude paths.
>
> The second batch file [uncompress_rar.bat](http://comptb.cects.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/uncompress_rar.bat_.txt) decompresses all .rar files
> from a folder and places the extracted files into another directory.
> Be sure to change the extension(s) to .bat before using either file.
>
> Both of the batch files temporarily set the Windows path
> environment variable for the WinRAR folder when executed.